# cloning files from server to a local folder - git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am super new to github and I need to know, how to clone a repository which is on the server to a local folder (local computer).

Assuming, x is the folder (destination on local computer) and y is the repository.

I presume gitclone is the option, could someone briefly explain?

Thanks!

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Comment: Saying "I am super new" does not mean you can then ask an unresearched question. Basic is fine, but for example [it's litterally the first result](https://www.google.es/search?q=how+to+clone+a+repository&oq=how+to+clone+a+repository&aqs=chrome..69i57.263j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). If you've already read references like this and are still confused - explain why so readers can address your specific point of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to copy the repository url,

go to the folder where you want to repository to be in and do a git clone.

```
#cd to the desired folder
cd folder

# grab the git repo to the desired folder inside this folder
git clone <url> <desired folder name>
```

Comment: The git repo is actually on the server and I'm not sure how to get the url?

Answer (score 0):

As CodeWizard says, it's simply a matter of git cloning the repository url.
You can find that url on GitHub by navigating to the project you want to clone/fork, clicking on the green `Clone or download` button on the right-hand side, and then copying the url that is shown. Then use that url for `git clone`.

For example, say I want to clone firejail. I first navigate to the [GitHub page for firejail](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail). Then I click on `Clone or download`, which shows me https://github.com/netblue30/firejail.git as the repository url.

Next, I navigate to the folder to which I want to clone firejail. (I am using bash on LMDE 2. Adjust for your operating system as necessary.)

```
cd Gitdir
git clone https://github.com/netblue30/firejail.git
```

Firejail is now cloned to Gitdir/firejail.

EDIT: Since you're new to github, I highly recommend these:

http://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1

http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2/